# Visual Studio 2015 not creaing Web project when creating Sharepoint Add-in

Tags: sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way to force visual studio 2015 to create Sharepoint add-in with web project? It worked before but now not anymore. I remember I installed some plugins, maybe that is the cause of it. Now when creating a Sharepoint Online Add-in project, no web project is created on the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try these two options.

**Option 1**

1. Go to AppSettings of SharePoint AddIn project and change from Provider hosted to SharePoint hosted. Save and build the project.
2. Change back to Provider hosted and this time it should ask you to create a MVC project.

**Option 2**

1. Create a SharePoint AddIn project with SharePoint hosted option.
2. Change the setting to Provider hosted and it should ask to create a MVC project